# how to pass twig code from javascript to twig file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I want to create a registration form for agent, but one agent should be able to register how many agent they want.

User complete fields (name, surname etc..) and they must answer the question:
Would you like add new agent? -> look add code:

```
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="new_agent">Would you like add new agent:</label>
                <div class="radio new_agent_div">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="new_agent" id="new_agent" value="1"> Yes
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="new_agent" id="new_agent2" value="0" > No
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="add-agents"></div>
```

if they checked Yes I run jquery code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".new_agent_div").change(function(){


        var html = [
            '               <div class="form-group">',
            '                   <label for="name">First Name</label>',
            '                   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{app.request.get("name")}}" placeholder="">',
            '                   {% if validation["name"][0] is defined %}',
            '                       <span class="help-block">',
            '                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>',
            '                           {{validation["name"][0]}}',
            '                       </span>',
            '                   {% endif %}',
            '               </div>'
        ].join('');

        if ($('#new_agent').is(':checked')) {
            $('.add-agents').html(html);
        }

        if ($('#new_agent2').is(':checked')) {
            $('.add-agents').html('');
        }

    });    
});
```

After that should be displayed again if add new user...

What's a problem? When I click 'Yes' I received Twig tags as string. Look:
[twig tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iwTm.png)

What should I do? Maybe some filters or something like this?

Comment: where did you put your javascript code? You must put it in twig file xxx.html.twig

Answer (score 1):

Why you did not put the html by default and hide/show when the radio value changes?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="new_agent">Would you like add new agent:</label>
    <div class="radio new_agent_div">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="new_agent" id="new_agent" value="1"> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="new_agent" id="new_agent2" value="0" > No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="add-agents" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{app.request.get("name")}}" placeholder="">
        {% if validation["name"][0] is defined %}
            <span class="help-block">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
                {{validation["name"][0]}}
            </span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the js looks like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".new_agent_div").change(function(){

        if ($('#new_agent').is(':checked')) {
            $('.add-agents').css("display" , "block");
        }

        if ($('#new_agent2').is(':checked')) {
            $('.add-agents').css("display" , "none");
        }

    });    
});
```